# Angular date conversation to moment for formControl

Tags: angular, angular-moment

I need to use moment with dates.I am getting confused here and caused lot of bugs. I am trying to introduce moment with dates in my code without breaking anything.This is working code, works fine in chrome but in IE, year shows incorrect. For year instead of 19 as 2019, it shows 1919. After researching, I came to know this problem can be fixed by using moment.

//Start date need to be fixed

```
  <div class="schedule-release-date" *ngIf="formControls['releaseEntryType'].value === 1">
      <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="">
        <input required matInput [matDatepicker]="releaseDatePicker" placeholder="Release Date" [formControl]="formControls['startDate']">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="releaseDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #releaseDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>


 entryTypeChanged(event: MatSelectChange) {
    if (
      event.value &&
      event.value === 1
    ) {
      this.displayDatePickerForScheduleReleases = true;
      if (!(this.releaseManagementInteractiveForm.get('startDate'))) {
        this.releaseManagementInteractiveForm.addControl(
          'startDate',
          new FormControl(new Date().toISOString())
        );
      } else {
        this.releaseManagementInteractiveForm.get('startDate').setValue(new Date().toISOString());
      }
    } else {
      this.displayDatePickerForScheduleReleases = false;
      this.releaseManagementInteractiveForm.removeControl(
        'startDate'
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install moment library

```
npm install moment  --save
```

Import and use in your Typescript file

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

incase if u get error in importing use

```
import  moment from 'moment';
```

for your case use replace

```
 new Date() to  moment.utc()
```

solves your issue

Comment: Thanks, Can you show me here, how can i use moment.js here. I used moment but i am getting confused with Angular forms

https://stackblitz.com/edit/datepicker-angular2

Comment: what exactly you want to make

Comment: a mat-datepicker is feed by an object Date, why do you convert to string?

Comment: @shashikumar 
not my code sorry 

  if (releaseEntryTypeId === 1) {
                this.releaseModificationItem.releaseManagementInteractiveForm
                .get('startDate')
                .setValue(moment.utc(this.releaseDetails.startDate).toISOString());
              }

I changed this but didnt work for me

Comment: @Eliseo its an existing code which i need to fix i think they did it to make the consistent format

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use moment for dates across your entire app, you should import `MatMomentDateModule` in `app.module` instead of `MatNativeDateModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [MatDatepickerModule, MatMomentDateModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

this has a dependency on moment, so you need to install moment as well.

[Angular Material - Choosing a date implementation and date format settings](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)